# azure document intelligence API PRebuilt-layout with KeyValuePairs feature (C# SDK)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-form-recognizer, azure-ai

The following code is throwing an Invalid argument error on KeyValuePairs while keyValuePairs feature exists and is valid. Can you help explain?

```
AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-layout", fileUri, new AnalyzeDocumentOptions() { Features = { DocumentAnalysisFeature.KeyValuePairs } });
```

Error message: Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Invalid argument. Status: 400 (Bad Request) ErrorCode: InvalidArgument Content: {"error":{"code":"InvalidArgument","message":"Invalid argument.","innererror":{"code":"InvalidParameter","message":"The parameter keyValuePairs is invalid: The feature is invalid or not supported."}}}

I tried all below feature and they work, but keyvaluepairs feature don't work.

```
AnalyzeDocumentOptions options = new AnalyzeDocumentOptions();
options.Features.Add(DocumentAnalysisFeature.Barcodes);
options.Features.Add(DocumentAnalysisFeature.Formulas);
options.Features.Add(DocumentAnalysisFeature.Languages);
options.Features.Add(DocumentAnalysisFeature.FontStyling);
options.Features.Add(DocumentAnalysisFeature.OcrHighResolution);
```

Comment: The prebuilt-layout model extracts text and text locations, tables, selection marks, and structure information from documents and images. You can extract key/value pairs using the layout model with the optional query string parameter features=keyValuePairs enabled.

Answer (score 0):

- The  code below is using the Azure Form Recognizer SDK in C# to analyze a document for key-value pairs

**Prerequisites:**

- Create an Azure AI services or Document Intelligence [single-service](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesFormRecognizer) or [multi-service](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesAllInOne).
- To connect your application to the Azure Document Intelligence service:

1. After your resource deploys, select **Go to resource**.
2. In the left navigation menu, select **Keys and Endpoint**.
3. Copy one of the keys and the **Endpoint** for use later in this article.

- Use Document Intelligence client library SDKs or REST API - Azure AI [services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/how-to-guides/use-sdk-rest-api?view=doc-intel-4.0.0&tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#use-the-general-document-model).
- Code taken from [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/how-to-guides/use-sdk-rest-api?view=doc-intel-4.0.0&tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#use-the-general-document-model).

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FR_KEY");
        string endpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FR_ENDPOINT");
        AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key);
        DocumentAnalysisClient client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new Uri(endpoint), credential);

        // Replace the fileUri with the actual URI of the document you want to analyze
        Uri fileUri = new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample-layout.pdf");

        AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-document", fileUri);
        AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;

        Console.WriteLine("Detected key-value pairs:");

        foreach (DocumentKeyValuePair kvp in result.KeyValuePairs)
        {
            if (kvp.Value == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  Found key with no value: '{kvp.Key.Content}'");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  Found key-value pair: '{kvp.Key.Content}' and '{kvp.Value.Content}'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hello,

You are using the "prebuilt-document" in your code instead of "prebuilt-layout".
I want to extract key/value pairs using the layout model.

Comment: good that you found a solution Layout [model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/how-to-guides/use-sdk-rest-api?view=doc-intel-4.0.0&tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#use-the-layout-model)

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved now.
I was using the The Azure.AI.FormRecognizer 4.1.0 which defaults to the 2023-07-31 version of the service. The Document Intelligence public preview version defaults to REST API version 2023-10-31-preview.
I had to add the pre-release version of the Azure.AI.DocumentIntelligence package to my project.